# Retrieve html using imap_fetchbody

Tags: php, cakephp, imap, gmail-imap

i am using imap to retrieve emails. It works fine for fine for plain text. But problem getting html, I use `imap_fetchbody($connections,$email_number,1.2);` but it does not work. It returns  null. But if I try `imap_fetchbody($connections,$email_number,1.1);` which is for plain text I get `*` instead of html tag.

I appreciate any help

Comment: what code are you using? selfmade one? also: what cake version?

Comment: Have you tried using `imap_fetchbody( $connections, $email_number, NULL );` and printing its result?

Comment: @mark the project is an old one it is on cake 1.3

Answer (score 3):

As per PHP specifications

```
 string imap_fetchbody ( resource $imap_stream , int $msg_number , string $section [, int $options = 0 ] )
```

Just Remember that the number should be the string not the integer thus your command would be

```
 imap_fetchbody($connections,$email_number,"1.2");
```

Hope this would resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

The html you are using, might be missing MIME type. You can give it a try using `"<!DOCTYPE html> <html>"` in starting of the mail content.