# php imap not reading body message without attachment

Tags: php, imap

I have written php code for reading email. I am using

```
imap_fetchbody($this->conn, $i, 1.2);
```

for displaying email message. When mail is with attachment it is display in well mannered but if email is without attachment it displays nothing. When I am using

```
$body = imap_fetchbody($this->conn, $i, 1);
```

message is displaying in text/plain format. like this

```
this is system generated mail -- Regards! Md Belal
```

When I am using

```
$body = imap_body($this->conn, $i);
```

it is displaying like this

```
--047d7b5d2f88ddb36c050069a175 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 this is system generated mail -- Regards! Md Belal 8287326270 --047d7b5d2f88ddb36c050069a175 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable 

this is system generated mail

-- 


Regards!
Md Belal
--047d7b5d2f88ddb36c050069a175--
```

I need to display it in well mannered. Like this.

```
this is system generated mail

-- 


Regards!
Md Belal
```

What to do please help. Thanks!

Comment: You need to fetch the body structure, parse it, and then decide what is the body.  Emails can be sent in a myriad of ways, and "1.2" isn't always the body, and may not even exist.  For example, if the email is plain-text or html-only, it will only have one part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14936048/2289510

btw i haven't tried but nl2br (http://hu1.php.net/nl2br) may can help you too, its adding line breaks when your result is in text/plain format and its contains \n \r characters.

Comment: not exactly displaying as the message with attachment displaying but still displaying better than earlier. Thanks btw.